# Can PyChef be used to upload cookbook?

Tags: python, chef-infra, knife, pychef

I want to upload cookbooks through a python program , without using knife utility.
I tried looking at PyChef to understand if there is an api call to do so , however it looks like PyChef only allows to fetch details and manipulate chef objects (nodes , environment , role and databags). But there is no call specific to uploading a cookbook.

Is there any way we can upload cookbook and may be bootstrap a node using a python program but without setting up and using knife ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is 2 PR's that adds support for cookboks but they were never merged.

See: https://github.com/coderanger/pychef

The project looks like it has been dead for about a year now.

You could try to fork the project and merge the PR's yourself and see if it works.

Comment: maybe you have link to alrternative, but still alive project?